# Удалить повторные значения свойства "name" в объекте useState

Tags: javascript, массивы, reactjs, объекты, react-hook

Удалить повторяющиеся сво-ва в объекте, который в массиве useState. Затем полученный уникальные массив с объектами запушить в другой useState

Пример:

```
const[arr, setArr] = useState([ /* ввод  */
    {name: "Sp. Moscow", games: 22},
    {name: "Sp. Moscow", games: 12},
    {name: "Krasnodar", games: 52},
    {name: "Zenit", games: 52},
    {name: "Krasnodar", games: 2},
]);
const[uniqueArr, setUniqueArr] = useState([]);
```

....

```
const[uniqueArr, setUniqueArr] = useState([ /* выход - p.s: заметьте, удаляем второй повторяющийся объект */
    {name: "Sp. Moscow", games: 22},
    {name: "Krasnodar", games: 52},
    {name: "Zenit", games: 52},
]);
```

По

Answer (score 2):

Для удаления повторяющихся объектов из массива можно воспользоваться методом **reduce()**. Метод **reduce()** применяет функцию к каждому элементу массива и аккумулирует результаты в одном значении, которое в конечном итоге станет итоговым значением. В данном случае, мы будем использовать **reduce()** для сбора уникальных объектов на основе их свойств:

```
const[arr, setArr] = useState([
    {name: "Sp. Moscow", games: 22},
    {name: "Sp. Moscow", games: 12},
    {name: "Krasnodar", games: 52},
    {name: "Zenit", games: 52},
    {name: "Krasnodar", games: 2},
]);

const[uniqueArr, setUniqueArr] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
  setUniqueArr(
    arr.reduce((accumulator, current) => {
      // Проверяем, есть ли объект с таким же значением свойств в аккумуляторе
      const match = accumulator.find(obj => obj.name === current.name && obj.games === current.games);
      // Если объекта с таким же значением свойств нет, добавляем текущий объект в аккумулятор
      if (!match) {
        accumulator.push(current);
      }
      return accumulator;
    }, [])
  );
}, [arr]);
```

Здесь мы используем **useEffect()** для того, чтобы обновить состояние **uniqueArr**, когда состояние arr меняется.
Функция **reduce()** принимает два аргумента: функцию обратного вызова и начальное значение аккумулятора.
Функция обратного вызова принимает два аргумента: аккумулятор и текущий элемент массива. Внутри функции обратного вызова мы проверяем, есть ли объект с таким же значением свойств в аккумуляторе. Если объекта нет, мы добавляем текущий объект в аккумулятор. В конце мы возвращаем аккумулятор как итоговое значение.

Comment: Стоит упомянуть, что **useEffect** будет срабатывать каждый раз при изменении состояния переменной **arr** и если этого не требуется, то список зависимостей надо поставить пусто

Answer (score 0):

> Удалить повторяющиеся сво-ва в объекте, который в массиве useState. Затем полученный уникальные массив с объектами запушить в другой useState

Предложу такой вариант...

```js
const arr = [ /* ввод  */
    {name: "Sp. Moscow", games: 22},
    {name: "Sp. Moscow", games: 12},
    {name: "Krasnodar", games: 52},
    {name: "Zenit", games: 52},
    {name: "Krasnodar", games: 2},
]
const a = test(arr)
console.log(a)
// потом можно сетить
//setUniqueArr(a)

// удаляем повторения
function test(a) {
  const s = new Set()
  return a.filter(o => {
    if (s.has(o.name)) return false
    s.add(o.name)
    return true
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Если надо выполнить преобразование только один раз, при монтировании компонента, то можно сделать так:

```
const[arr, setArr] = useState([ /* ввод  */
  {name: "Sp. Moscow", games: 22},
  {name: "Sp. Moscow", games: 12},
  {name: "Krasnodar", games: 52},
  {name: "Zenit", games: 52},
  {name: "Krasnodar", games: 2},
]);

const[uniqueArr, setUniqueArr] = useState(arr.reduce((acc, it) => {
  if (!acc.find(el => el.name === it.name)) acc.push(it);
  return acc;
}, []));
```